# flutter run command not working as expected

Tags: android, flutter, dart

running `flutter run` on the current directory of the project file would run the project in connected device. However, recently after doing the said command. It would stop on

```
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                17.1s
Uninstalling old version...
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                23.7s
```

After this terminal log. I expected a log that says r for hot reload and R for Restart. But apparently its not working anymore. As well as f5 and ctrl+f5 is worse as it does not display in the app device (Only white screen). Please help!

Here is my `flutter doctor -v`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1139], locale en-PH)
    • Flutter version 1.22.4 at C:\Dev\flutter
    • Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (3 weeks ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
    • Engine revision 2c956a31c0
    • Dart version 2.10.4


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • vivo 1601 (mobile) • <device id> • android-arm64 • Android 6.0 (API 23)
```

Note: I replaced some words enclosed with "<>" for privacy reasons.

Comment: Can show us your `Flutter` version using `flutter doctor -v` ?

Comment: Hi! I edited the post with the return of ```flutter doctor -v``` command

Comment: Let's try this, uninstall your app from your emulator or mobile and try running it.

Comment: I did. Same result :( . I have reinstalled flutter but still the same. The only alternative solution for me to attach the debugger is to use ```flutter attach``` manually in a device.

Comment: did you try after running `flutter clean` ?

Comment: Yes I also did try ```flutter clean```. I'm trying to reinstall android studio incase it might have been the reason. Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Try an invalidate caches and restart

Goto FIle -> Invalidate Caches / Restar